# ngnix URL with context(virtual) path

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

My ngix site config file is given below. I want to add context path to my URL

I can access site by http://localhost:8888, but I want to add context path to my site URL like http://localhost:8888/MyApp

```
server {
    listen       8888;
    server_name  localhost;
   location{
        root    "C:/nginx/Share/dist";
    index  index.html index.htm;

   }
```

}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the base location for this

```
server {
    listen       8888;
    server_name  localhost;
   location / {
     # since we have nothing on root we can redirect to /MyApp/ if we want
     return 302 /MyApp;
   }

   location /MyApp {
        root    "C:/nginx/Share/dist";
    index  index.html index.htm;

   }
}
```

Comment: I tried giving the same way, but now http://localhost:8888/MyApp throwing "404 not found" error.

Comment: Try using `alias` instead of `root`